# Regex is not working as expected - determining if a path is correct

Tags: php, regex

I am having a hard time finishing a regex to catch a correct pattern in my files.

This is my PHP Code that I let run:

```
$imagesToAdd = [];
foreach (glob($imagePath.'/'.$groupCode.'*.{jpg,png}', GLOB_BRACE) as $filepath) {
    $match = (int) preg_match('#'.$imagePath.'/'.$groupCode.'+([^\D]|[-_\d]?)+.(png|jpg)#', $filepath);
    print $filepath . PHP_EOL;
    print $imagePath.'/'.$groupCode.'+(|[\D]|[-_\d])+.(png|jpg)' . PHP_EOL;
    var_dump($match);
    if ($match !== 0) {
        $imagesToAdd[] = $filepath;
    }
}
```

The Regex here is `'#'.$imagePath.'/'.$groupCode.'+([^\D]|[-_\d]?)+.(png|jpg)#'`.
Lets use some examples to make clear what my objective is and why its still failing.

Lets say the Regex resolves to this:

```
\/home\/shop\/test\/release\/20211005131411\/pub\/media\/productImages\/29192-7+([^\D]|[-_\d]?)+.(png|jpg)
```

it will correctly fetch the provided path as expected. But now comes my problem.

My `$groupCode` can be either `1`, `1-1` or `1123123123-1` or simply only `1123123123`. In any case, `1` should not match a provided path that ends onto `123123123-1.png` or `12111111.jpg`.

So, if the `$groupCode` is 1, it should only match `1.jpg` or `1.png` or `1-1.png` or `1-9999.jpg`.

If the `$groupCode` is `123-1` it should only match `123-1.jpg` or `123-1.png` or `123-1-anyothernumber.(png|jpg)`. What do I have to do in order to get the Regex straight here?

My current approach does not work completely and I am running out of ideas.

Comment: First of all, escape the literal `.` in the pattern, `\.(png|jpg)`. Also, `[^\D]` = `\d`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew of course! Thanks for the heads up! I am really not a Regex Expert, so these comments are pretty helpful to become better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First replace the `glob()` with some static data to get a reproducible example. It is really difficult for us to debug something if we do not have all parts.

```
$data = [
    '/base-path/42.png',
    '/base-path/42-1.png',
    '/base-path/42.PNG',
    '/base-path/21.png'
];
$imagePath = '/base-path';
$groupCode = '42';
```

Some things to look out for:

- If you put a variable value into a regular expression, you will need to escape the special characters that might be in it - use `preg_quote()`.
- Validating patterns need to be anchored, otherwise here can be content before and after - use `^` and `$`.

If I understand correctly you're trying to match:

`{path}/{code}.{image-extension}` and
`{path}/{code}-{digits}.{image-extension}`

- Digit: `\d`
- Digits (at least one): `\d+`
- Prefixed with -: `-\d+`
- Optional: `(-\d+)?`
- With image file extension: `(-\d+)?\.(jpg|png)`
- Case insensitive extensions: `(-\d+)?\.((?i)jpg|png)`

Put together:

```
$pattern = '(^'.preg_quote($imagePath.'/'.$groupCode).'(-\d+)?\\.((?i)png|jpg)$)';
var_dump($pattern);

$imagesToAdd = [];
foreach ($data as  $file) {
    echo 'Validating: ', $file, PHP_EOL;
    $found = preg_match($pattern, $file);
    echo $found ? ' - HIT' : ' - MISS', PHP_EOL;
    if ($found) {
        $imagesToAdd[] = $file;
    }
}

var_dump($imagesToAdd);
```

Output:

```
string(40) "(^/base\-path/42(-\d+)?\.((?i)png|jpg)$)"
Validating: /base-path/42.png
 - HIT
Validating: /base-path/42-1.png
 - HIT
Validating: /base-path/42.PNG
 - HIT
Validating: /base-path/21.png
 - MISS
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(17) "/base-path/42.png"
  [1]=>
  string(19) "/base-path/42-1.png"
  [2]=>
  string(17) "/base-path/42.PNG"
}
```

Comment: Great, it seems this solves my problem! I've added (-|_), to fetch also _ delimiters, but overall, this perfectly works!! Thanks a lot!